# Extract archive in ruby on windows

Tags: ruby, windows, zip, archive

I am having trouble extracting a zip-archive on a windows machine.
I am currently working on an extension for buildr, which works fine on Linux and Mac OS X.
I am using a built-in function in buildr to extract my archive which is built on top of rubyzip but rubyzip fails on windows with:

> NotImplementedError : symlink() function is unimplemented on this machine

Anyone knows how I can make this work on Windows.

Comment: Can you point to the package are you trying to extract? Symlinks in zip files are problematic as windows lack symlinks in the sense of *NIX like ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install unzip, put it in your system path, and then simply

```
myfile = "foo.zip"
`unzip #{myfile}`
```

The `` `...` `` command in Ruby allows you to execute system commands.

Comment: I would like to go without system dependencies, as i am distributing this as a gem and want to work it out-of-the box if possible.
I could of course, add another gem as a dependency.

Comment: I now tried every gem I could find and it seems i have to go with unzip. Works fine. Thanks.